# Keras Linear regression model from images not predicting correctly

Tags: image, keras, model, regression

I have images which are rated as 0 to 5 (they corresponds to the visual attractiveness of a manufactured part). When training, the mean absolute error gets down to .4. However, when I plot the actual vs predicted at the very end of the code, there is no correlation between actual and predicted. I exported the table of actual vs predicted and imported to Excel and when I calculate mean absolute error, I get a values of 1.2 (again  reports .4). The Rsq of actual vs. predicted is less than .01. Its like my prediction at the end is random and doesn't use the model.

Towards the bottom, you will see "#test_generator.reset()". This was my attempt to troubleshoot the problem but with and without this line does nothing. I know how to change the model to make the model ordinal, but I'm looking to make this model quantitative.

```
import pandas as pd
import os
from .preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from .callbacks import ModelCheckpoint
from .models import Sequential
from .layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from .layers import Activation, Dropout, Flatten, Dense
from  import backend as K
from .utils import multi_gpu_model
from  import optimizers
from matplotlib import pyplot
import cv2



listOfFoldersWithImages = ["C:\\ImageFoler"]
BATCH_SIZE =32
TARGET_SIZE = 300,300 
INPUT_SHAPE = 300,300,3 
NUM_EPOCHS =50

MODEL_WEIGHTS_LOAD_FILENAME = 'Quant_Weights1_Complex.h5'  #optional - leave blank if not desired
MODEL_WEIGHTS_SAVE_FILENAME = 'Quant_Weights1_Complex.h5' #optionally leave blank
ENTIRE_MODEL_SAVE_FILENAME = 'Quant_Model1_Complex.h5'  #optionally leave blank
MY_LOSS = 'mae'

CLASS_MODE = 'other'

def RecursivelySearchForImageFiles(listOfPaths):
    listAllRatings = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"]
    files = []
    ratings = []
    for path in listOfPaths:
        # r=root, d=directories, f = files
        for r, d, f in os.walk(path):
            for file in f:
                if (len(file)>=17):
                    if (file[1:17] == "=CNNPartRated___"):
                        strNum = file[0:1]
                        if (strNum in listAllRatings):
                            files.append (os.path.join(r, file))
                            ratings.append(int(strNum))  #numerical

    return files, ratings



listOfAllImagesPaths, listOfAllRatings = RecursivelySearchForImageFiles(listOfFoldersWithImages)


print ("Number of 0 = " + str(listOfAllRatings.count(0)))
print ("Number of 1 = " + str(listOfAllRatings.count(1)))
print ("Number of 2 = " + str(listOfAllRatings.count(2)))
print ("Number of 3 = " + str(listOfAllRatings.count(3)))
print ("Number of 4 = " + str(listOfAllRatings.count(4)))
print ("Number of 5 = " + str(listOfAllRatings.count(5)))



traindf = pd.DataFrame( {'path': listOfAllImagesPaths, 'rating': listOfAllRatings })
traindf = traindf.sample(frac=1).reset_index(drop=True)

datagen=ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255,validation_split=0.25)

train_generator=datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
    dataframe=traindf,
    directory="None",
    x_col="path",
    y_col="rating",
    subset="training",
    batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
    seed=42,
    shuffle=True,
    class_mode="other",
    #save_to_dir=SAVE_TO_DIR,
    target_size=TARGET_SIZE)

valid_generator=datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
    dataframe=traindf,
    directory="None",
    x_col="path",
    y_col="rating",
    subset="validation",
    batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
    seed=42,
    shuffle=True,
    class_mode="other",
    #save_to_dir=SAVE_TO_DIR,
    target_size=TARGET_SIZE)

test_datagen=ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255.)

test_generator=test_datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
    dataframe=traindf,
    directory="None",
    x_col="path",
    y_col=None,
    batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
    seed=42,
    shuffle=False,
    class_mode=None,
    target_size=TARGET_SIZE)





def TinyModel():
    model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu', input_shape=INPUT_SHAPE))
    model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))

    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(256))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Dense(64))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Dense(1, activation='linear'))
    return model


model = TinyModel()


parallel_model = multi_gpu_model(model, gpus=2)

parallel_model.compile(optimizers.rmsprop(lr=0.0001, decay=1e-6),loss=MY_LOSS,metrics=[MY_LOSS])

if (MODEL_WEIGHTS_LOAD_FILENAME):
    model.load_weights(MODEL_WEIGHTS_LOAD_FILENAME)

STEP_SIZE_TRAIN=train_generator.n//train_generator.batch_size
STEP_SIZE_VALID=valid_generator.n//valid_generator.batch_size
STEP_SIZE_TEST=test_generator.n//test_generator.batch_size


checkpoint_name = 'Weights-{epoch:03d}--{val_loss:.5f}.hdf5'
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(checkpoint_name, monitor='val_loss', verbose = 1, save_weights_only=True, save_best_only = True, mode ='auto')
callbacks_list = [checkpoint]

history = parallel_model.fit_generator(generator=train_generator,
                    steps_per_epoch=STEP_SIZE_TRAIN,
                    validation_data=valid_generator,
                    validation_steps=STEP_SIZE_VALID,
                    epochs=NUM_EPOCHS,
                    callbacks=callbacks_list
                    )

if (MODEL_WEIGHTS_SAVE_FILENAME!=''):
    model.save_weights(MODEL_WEIGHTS_SAVE_FILENAME)

if (ENTIRE_MODEL_SAVE_FILENAME!=''):
    model.save(ENTIRE_MODEL_SAVE_FILENAME)


pyplot.plot(history.history['mean_absolute_error'])
pyplot.plot(history.history['val_mean_absolute_error'])
pyplot.title('model mean_absolute_error ')
pyplot.ylabel('mean_absolute_error')
pyplot.xlabel('epoch')
pyplot.legend(['train', 'test'], loc='upper left')
pyplot.show()

#test_generator.reset()
pred=parallel_model.predict_generator(test_generator,
    steps=STEP_SIZE_TEST+1,
    verbose=1)



pyplot.plot(listOfAllRatings, pred, 'o', color='black')
pyplot.show()
outframe = pd.DataFrame( {'actual': listOfAllRatings, 'predicted': pred.tolist() })
outframe.to_csv(listOfFoldersWithImages[0]+"\\correlation.csv")
print ("File exported")
```